# Prove key of leaf is larger or smaller than key of parent if leaf is largest key in smaller tree or smallest in larger tree with respect to parent

Tags: trees, binary-trees

Show that for any leaf v in a binary search tree, if u is the parent of v, then either key[v] is the largest key in the tree smaller than key[u], or key[v] is the smallest key in the tree larger than key[u].

I don't understand "key[v] is the largest key in the tree smaller than key[u]" and "key[v] is the smallest key in the tree larger than key[u]." Can someone help explain the problem to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Order** traversal sorts key in an ascending order. If $u$ is the parent of leaf $v$ then $v$ is either left or right child of $u$. If $v$ is left child then $key[v]\leq key[u]$ which implies $key[v]$ is the largest key in the tree smaller than $key[u]$. Similar intuition follows if $v$ is right child.